# iOS Simulator download and install fails - XCode 6.4 on El-Capitan 10.11 beta

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I get the following error message:

> Could not download and install iOS 7.1 Simulator. Authorization is required to install the packages.

The issue is for XCode 7 beta versions too. I have tried the latest one available as of today on developer.apple.com

I think it is related to OS upgrade to El-Capitan as Simulator downloads work pretty fine for my other colleagues working on Yosemite still, for both XCode 6.4 and XCode 7 beta versions. What could be causing this error and how do I solve it?

Comment: I've seen some other reports of this problem as well.  I suggest you file a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: I am experiencing this as well. After close to 2 hours of downloading the simulator (tried 8.1, 8.2, and 8.3), it says "Authorization is required".

Comment: i'm facing this issues too, took me an hour to download ios 7.1 simulator then says "Authorization ...", using xcode 6.1 and Elcaptain.

Answer (score 7):

Running command in terminal `sudo /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode` and then download the simulator 7.1 works for me. I'm using Xcode 6.1, osx El Captain.

Comment: It's really answer! It launches another XCode app, that should be used (we use wrong app)

Comment: It does not matter. It launches another Xcode app, close and open the 6.4 version or the other and then download the sim 7.1. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is user interface issue in xcode 6.4 installed on El capitan. When you make xcode full screen, you can see the list of simulator.

Comment: i don't understand your answers.

Comment: @thanh If you are running Xcode 6.4 on El Capitan. List of simulator will not appear. But when you keep Xcode in "Full screen", you can see the list. Workaround: Go to menu Product-->Destination. you can see list of all devices as well as simulator.